# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm staring with Laravel and I'm having troubles trying to make a simple insert, but It seems that all of my fillable fields are not being included. This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value 
(SQL: insert into `addresses` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (2017-12-25 09:31:49, 2017-12-25 09:31:49))
```

As you can see, only `created_at` and `updated_at` are about to be inserted, I thought that maybe I forgot my `fillable` vars, but this is my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Addresses extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'city',
    'suburb',
    'street',
    'o_number',
    'i_number',
    'postal_code',
    'phone_s',
    'email_s',
    'google_map',
    'customer_id'
];

}
```

And the Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Addresses;
use App\Customers;

class AddressesController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function store(Request $request){

    $create = Addresses::create([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'city' => request('city'),
        'suburb' => request('suburb'),
        'street' => request('street'),
        'o_number' => request('o_number'),
        'i_number' => request('i_number'),
        'postal_code' => request('postal_code'),
        'phone_s' => request('phone_s'),
        'email_s' => request('email_s'),
        'google_map' => request('google_map'),
        'customer_id' => Customers::where('code',$request->session()->get('customer_code'))->first()->id
    ]);

    $success = $create ? $request->session()->flash('success', '¡Registro exitoso!') : $request->session()->flash('success', 'Ooops! Algo salio mal :(');

    return redirect('addresses/'.$request->session()->get('customer_code'));
 }
}
```

Echo the `request()` values works! So I'm missing right now, I have some other Models and Controller working good in the same way. Please Help!

Answer (score 15):

This error show because you the NAME field is required on your database. Try to edit your migration script and put default value on this field or make it nullable.

eg.

`$table->string('name')->nullable();`

OR

`$table->string('name')->default('');`

Then run a migration refresh.

Comment: If I do that only change in the message: `name` for `customer_id`, and both fields as `phone_s` are necessary for my purposes, and still not inserting nothing

Comment: hmmm. I think the error is on the way you call the  $request method. Try to call the variables using $request->name, $request->city, etc..

Comment: I tried but still the same problem, like I said @jun drie I have another Controller working good and is written in same way

Answer (score 14):

Goto "phpmyadmin" >> "Variables" then find "sql_mode" edit and remove "STRICT_ALL_TABLES or STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"

It is working for me.
Hope it will help for All.

[image]

Comment: WOW, thanks. This was so anoying, just trying to redeploy an old toy project and this was killing me

Answer (score 13):

This is late answer for this question, but it might help for others.
This error can be occurred due to error in $fillable data in modal.
You  can try using

```
protected $guarded = []
```

instead of

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'city',
    'suburb',
    'street',
    'o_number',
    'i_number',
    'postal_code',
    'phone_s',
    'email_s',
    'google_map',
    'customer_id'
];
```

But You have to validate the data that you passed within the controller.

Comment: life saver! I had a stupid error in my $fillable array. Thanks

Comment: That was the answer

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs due to the strict mode of MYSQL5.7. Please change your config/database.php in the connections.mysql section by putting 'strict' => false.

Comment: This worked for me. But please what are the security implications for this?

Comment: This worked for me as well

Answer (score 3):

I solved it using `save()`

```
$addresses = new Addresses;
$customer_id = Customers::where('code',$request->session()->get('customer_code'))->first()->id;

    $addresses->name = $request->name;
    $addresses->city = $request->city;
    $addresses->suburb = $request->suburb;
    $addresses->street = $request->street;
    $addresses->o_number = $request->onumber;
    $addresses->i_number = $request->inumber;
    $addresses->postal_code = $request->postal_code;
    $addresses->phone_s = $request->phone_s;
    $addresses->email_s = $request->email_s;
    $addresses->google_map = $request->map;
    $addresses->customer_id = $customer_id;

    $success = $addresses->save() ? $request->session()->flash('success', '¡Registro exitoso!') : $request->session()->flash('success', 'Ooops! Algo salio mal :(');

    return redirect('addresses/'.$request->session()->get('customer_code'));
```

It's working properly

Answer (score 2):

When you use the nullable() method on a field, that field will default to NULL.

For example, add this to your migration file:

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

**Update:**

You can add:

```
$table->string('name')->nullable()->default(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check **Null** option in table structure, like this -

[image]

Comment: Okay, try by setting default value as blank in the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure request() has key 'name'.Replace request('name') to random string and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem because I didn't add a correct column under `$fillable` list.

```php
class Chirp extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'message', // This line should be added.
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @pukhraj_suthar (https://stackoverflow.com/users/987135/pukhraj-suthar) this happens when there are more columns in table than that are being added/updated, if so, error contains the name of first column in table that's extra/not being added/updated,
deleting or altering sequence doesn't help, error just shifts to next column name (in case more than extra columns), until all except required are deleted.
But changing SQL MODE either directly in phpmyadmin or in your database config file does the job.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to change - this is my code on my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $message = new Message();
    $message->name = $request->input('name');
    $message->name = $request->input('message');
    $message->save();
}
```

I made a duplication of the 'name' that's why it happened and made this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $message = new Message();
    $message->name = $request->input('name');
    $message->message = $request->input('message');
    $message->save();
}
```

This way the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Valid the request data in the controller.

$request->validate(['name'=>'required']);

Answer (score 0):

The previous feedback  solved your issue.
I just would like to add that once can get the exact same error message if the related field is not declared mass assignable (in the `$fillable` array) but tries to save an entity (model instance) by assigning a value to it.