# General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value - Laravel 9.x

Tags: laravel

I am inserting data into my db using the following fields but when I try to insert, I keep getting this error General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value. I am using Laravel 9.x
What could I be doing wrong?

I have tried the following approaches but all not working.

Initially, This is how this migration looks like

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I saw this similar question [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974348/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1364-field-name-doesnt-have-a-default-value-l), and I followed some of the answers given by doing this but nothing worked

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('username')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And I tried making them default(''); still, nothing worked.

When I try using the nullable(); this is what I get in the database

[image: Image of database after using nullable() or default()]

This is my function

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|unique:users,username|min:3|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|max:255'
        ];
    }
```

This is my protected items

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
```

This is another similar question [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72152485/general-error-1364-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value-in-laravel-9-x) but does not help either

I have other similar questions but most of them are old and does not answer my question too

Comment: Your migration specifies the name as optional (`nullable`), but your set of validation rules require it (`required`), try replacing `required` with `nullable` in the `name` attribute of your `rules()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried but I got this feedback. 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Do you want name to be nullable or you want it required? If you want it nullable, then replace required with nullable in `rules()` method, keep `->nullable()` in migration and refresh the database. If you want it required, but you keep getting this error, then the `name` field is missing. To understand where the problem is would ne nice to see your controller method and html form